# LibreOffice can not save documents on shared SSH drive - all other applications can

Tags: networking, libreoffice, shared-folders

I'm having a problem with Libre Office (all the applications).  I can not save a file to any networked drive (using SSH to network).  I keep getting a message that I do not have the necessary user rights to save the file (even if the share is created by ROOT).  I have no problems with any other applications writing to other network drives.

I'm running Ubuntu 11.10-64

Comment: If the share is created by root without the `-o allow_other` option, it is an expected behavior.

Comment: I'm creating the share in Nautilus... I don't see any place to add such an option.  Can you recommend a way to create the share where I can add this option.

Comment: Are you using nautilus from root? You should use your user account.

Comment: I'm using Nautilus from my user account but I've tried creating the SSH share with root too... no luck.  I can, however, create the share with sshfs and all the necessary access is available.  I'm afraid for many users the Nautilus share approach is most common so a Nautilus solution would be great... thankjs

Answer (score 1):

should be fixed with https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libreoffice/+bug/792622
in LibreOffice 3.5.3 (default in Ubuntu 12.04).

Comment: Assuming that bug is causing this problem, it should be possible work around the problem by mounting the SSH share with `sshfs` on the command-line [as detailed here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSHFS).